# Perl, open and read

Tags: perl

how to get directory content, and read file in it ?

But i can't use commands and operators that included in this regexp:

```
/system|[)(\/}{`;,!\\*_]|open|exec|eval/
```

I think it's a very hard task and i don't known how to make it, please help me.

Comment: please rephrase question

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Seems like homework. For the directory you can take a look at `opendir`. What do you mean by _read file in it_?. Do you want to open the file without using `open`?

Comment: Looks like the professor forgot to prohibit `qx`.

Comment: @Matteo, `opendir` matches the provided regex pattern.

Comment: @ikegami: Ok but why? Is it homework?

Comment: Or worse: is this a check to avoid code injection that you want to bypass?

Comment: Closed because "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here"??? The OP was actually quite precise!!! The question is none of vague, incomplete, broad or rhetorical, and it can be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is homework, it's one of the worse questions I've seen, so I'm assuming it's not.

```
perl -E'say for glob chr 42'
```

or

```
perl -e'print qx^ ls ^'
```

or

```
perl -MFile::Find::Rule -MMIME::Base64 -E's^^decode_base64 "c2F5IGZvciBGaWxlOjpGaW5kOjpSdWxlLT5tYXhkZXB0aCgxKS0+aW4oJy4nKTs="^ee'
```

---

It's really hard because we can't use `opendir` or IO::Dir without using "`;`" or "`,`", can't use File::Find::Rule without using "`(`" and "`)`", etc.

Comment: The fact that you can't even use parenthesis and punctuation really seems as as code injection check.

Comment: @Matteo, ah yes, I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework assignment? If it is, you need to mark it as such.

Perl has commands to open, read, and close a directory.

- To open a directory, you use the [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html).
- To read a name of a file in the directory, you use the [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) command.
- Once you're done, you can use the [closedir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/closedir.html).

The commands work in a similar fashion as the standard `open`, `read`, and `close` commands.

Comment: `opendir` matches the provided regex pattern. Also rather hard to do without using `;` or `,`.

Comment: I'm not sure what that regex pattern suppose to mean. I figured it was a homework assignment, and the teacher didn't want them using `system ls` or `$foo = $(ls);` type of thing. I figured `open` was verboten` but `opendir` would have been allowed. Maybe this was one of those bar bets. I guess you could use `glob(*);`. Of course, that would include the semicolon.

Comment: You can't use `glob("*")` because `*`, `(` and `)` are forbidden. What kind of homework disallows `(` and `)` and forces you to do in one expression that which requires multiple statements to do properly. I think Matteo is right that the OP is trying to test or bypass injection prevention code.